# What's the difference between $.add and $.append JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering and couldn't get any best documentation that what's the difference between $.add and $.append when we have single element to add or append to a container.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: *Add:* http://api.jquery.com/add/ ; *Append:* http://api.jquery.com/append/ ; further : Add elements to the set of matched elements. where as Append:  Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements. **<Oh and I am not a down voter>** B-)

Comment: _"couldn't get any best documentation"_ - Where did you look? The jQuery doco explains it pretty clearly...

Comment: I've looked through the internet. and yes JQuery documentation explains this. But not everybody is not that technical to understand all what explained there. That's why these forums exist. @nnnnnn

Comment: @MuhammadZahidRiaz,

SO helps those who helps themeselves :)

If you dont get the jQuery docs, just put it in question itself. Like jQuery docs says 'blah blah blah...' but I am not getting it. Is it this or that ?

Comment: Yeah that mine mistake. I've to mention that I am not getting this from the JQuery docs.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) method constructs a new jQuery object from the union of those elements and the ones passed into the method. But it does not insert the element into the DOM, i.e using `.add()` the element will be added to the DOM but to see it in the page you have to insert it in the page using some [insertion](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/)/[append](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) method.

Comment: can you please clarify further? you say "… But it does not insert the element into the DOM, i.e using `.add()` the element will be added to the DOM …" Well, which is it, does it get inserted into the DOM or not?

Comment: @chharvey +++ I didn't get it neither

Comment: I think "added to DOM" is wrong. "added to the set of elements that you intend to manipulate" is more accurate.

Answer (score 39):

***They are not at all related.***

**.add()**

*Add elements to the set of matched elements.*

e.g.

If you want to do,

```
$('div').css('color':'red');
$('div').css('background-color':'yellow');
$('p').css('color':'red');
```

Then, you can do,

```
$('div').css('background-color':'yellow').add('p').css('color':'red');
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

**.append()**

*Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.*

```
$('div').append('p');
```

will append selected `p` on all selected `div` in dom.

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jashwant. Now this clear to me also. after getting the responses.

Answer (score 9):

**.add()**

```
for example:
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
</ul>
<p>a random paragraph</p>
```

to change the color of the `<li>` elements *AND* the `<p>` element to red, you could write:

```
$( "li" ).css( "background-color", "green" );
$( "p" ).css( "background-color", "green" );
```

or condensing the above by utilizing .**add()**

```
$( "li" ).add( "p" ).css( "background-color", "green" );
```

**.append()**

Will *create* a new element to add to the DOM and will appear as a child to the existing specified element.

```
<div>one</div>
<div>two</div>

<ol>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
</ol>

$("div").append('<p>');
```

will result in:

```
<div>one</div>
<p></p>
<div>two</div>
<p></p>

<ol>
  <li>item1</li>
  <p></p>
  <li>item2</li>
  <p></p>
 </ol>
```

Comment: why will a paragraph be appended to each list item? they aren't divs.

Comment: @tismle: Did you mean change the color to 'green?' Also the Append() result is incorrect; using Append() adds a child node, aka it will place the P element inside the each div not after.

Answer (score 4):

Add just adds the element to the jquery object, it does not add it into the DOM

Append adds the element into the DOM as the child.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are pretty clear. I just want to add one more thought to it.
.add() seems to be an abbreviation of "in ADDition to".

```
$('p').add('div').css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

seems like have the same effect as

```
$('p, div').css('background-color','yellow');});
```

, while the latter is the Multiple Selector in jquery.
Here is the link to Multiple Selector: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

the complete code to play with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <!-- import jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>paragraph one</p>
    <div>div second</div>
    
    <script>
    
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('p').add('div').css('background-color', 'yellow');
            //$('p, div').css('background-color','yellow');
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `add` method name could be misleading. `add` and `append` are quite different. Think of `add` as something like `combinedWith` - you are expanding the set of elements that you want to affect with some jQuery function.

In particular, despite the name `add` is not at all the opposite of `remove`.

As others have said, `add` will not affect the appearance of the page, and `append` probably will.

So if you say

```
$('p').add('#special').css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

both your p elements and the element with an id of `special` will be affected.